# kubectl run-ing a tarball'd image

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl

I am trying to run a [Nix-built](https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#ssec-pkgs-dockerTools-buildImage) Docker image in tarball form. With docker, `docker load -i <path>` followed by a `docker run` works fine. Now I've uploaded the tarball to Artifactory and am trying to run the image on K8s with something like:

```
$ kubectl run foo-service --image=<internal Artifactory>/foo-service/foo-service-latest.tar.gz
```

However all I see is:

```
NAME                 DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
foo-service          1         1         1            0           2h
```

Is it possible to load an image from a (remote) tarball in K8s? If yes, what is the command to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do that directly in Kubernetes.

You can do `docker load` and then `docker push` to a registry (you can host a [private registry](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/addons/registry/README.md) in Kubernetes or use a public one) and after that `kubectl run`.

Minikube also has a registry addon for local development.

Comment: While I agree with your answer wholeheartedly, as a thought experiment I bet it's possible to do what OP requested via `docker load` using `-v /var/run/docker.sock` and [initContainers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/)

Comment: That's an interesting idea! In general we would still have the problem of shipping the tarball to the init container in case it's on local storage.

Comment: Relatedly is there a `docker` command that lets me load an image from a tarball? Or do I have to do something like curl it and pipe into `docker load`?

Comment: Nope. `docker load` does not support URLs so `curl | docker load` is the way to go.